# FIELD INTEGRITY EXCEPTION -- Delete the Default WorkSpace?

Tags: developer-console

I am having problems with the `Developer Console` in the default `Workspace`. It seems that it can be solved if I delete the workspace. So, my question is:

If I delete the default workspace, shall I lose all my developments (apex, visualforce, etc...)?

Answer (score 3):

The workspace really just stores a view. What resources do you have open? What panes? Take a look at [Developer Console Workspaces](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_views.htm&language=en):

> When you switch to a different workspace or close the Developer Console, the state of the tabs (and the panels within the tabs) in the current workspace is saved. If you have not created a workspace, the configuration is saved as the Default workspace.

Deleting a workspace will not have any effect on your existing metadata (`Apex Classes`, `Visualforce Pages`, etc).

Note that you can create a new `Workspace` and switch to it without deleting the `Default`.